# Is comparing the thumbprint of a SSL certificate secure enough?

Tags: tls, certificates, .net

I was wondering if comparing the `X509Certificate2.Thumbprint` of two certificates count as a save way to identify if a certificate is correct or not.
Of course this would only work for specific certificates the app knows about and not for all connection via https.
In my app I have only a view connection I am opening via https and I could easily hold the thumbprint of those view certificates inside the app, comparing them when I open a connection to identify if the certificate is valid or not.
As far as I understand it, there are no attacking vectors with this approach.

Another question I have is on how the `X509Certificate2.Thumbprint` is generated and if this thumbprint changes if the certificate changes from self-signed to be signed by any CA.

Comment: See http://morgansimonsen.com/2013/04/16/understanding-x-509-digital-certificate-thumbprints/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for a start.

Comment: thanks the first site helped me alot, especially in answering my last question. The second site, obviously, I already knew.
But what about possible attack vectors? Are there any?

Comment: so after reading this it looks like that only comparing the thumbprints is a secure way to ensure that there website I am talking to is the one I think it is?